# Heap corruption while freeing memory

Tags: c, heap-corruption

I'm struggling with this piece of code. As the name suggests, function should return array of strings that represents all rotations of a string given as a parameter.

```
char **str_all_rotations(const char *data) 
{
    int i = 0; /* Loop counter */ 
    len = strlen(data); /* Len of input */ 

    /******************/
    /*  malloc memory */

    char **all_rotations = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)* len);
    char *double_data = (char*)malloc(len * 2 * sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
         all_rotations[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* len);
    }

    /*******************/
    /*  Rotations part */

    strcpy(double_data, data);
    strcpy(double_data + len, data);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        strncpy(all_rotations[i], double_data + i, len);
        all_rotations[i][len] = '\0';
    }

    free(double_data); /* Release memory */

    return all_rotations;
}
```

It works fine from algorithmic perspective, but a simple call of this function

```
char *str = "omgillsetyouonfire";
char **asdf = str_all_rotations(str);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) 
{
    free(asdf[i]);
}

free(asdf);
```

fails, because of heap corruption. I can't see whats wrong.
How does one even debug this kind of errors ?

Comment: include the complete minimal program. compile with debug ( -g ) and run gdb to find the point of segfault. and add these details to the question

Comment: You are forgetting about the null character

Comment: 1. [Do not cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495_), 2. Do not use `strlen()` like `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)`, it suggests that you don't understand c strings, the length of the string is computed on each iteration. 3. Again you don't understand c strings, your second `strcpy()` is writing one byte after the end of the buffer. 4. `sizeof(char)` is 1 bu definition.

Comment: The main suspects are your dynamic allocations, concentrate on them when debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your code

1. When you use

   ```
   strcpy(double_data + len, data);
   ```

   you copy one extra byte to `double_data`, the `nul` terminator which you didn't allocate space for, so you should allocate space like this

   ```
   char *double_data = malloc(2 * len + 1));
   ```
2. The same applies for the allocation in the `for` loop, namely

   ```
   all_rotations[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* len);
   ```

   and of course the fix would be

   ```
   all_rotations[i] = malloc(1 + len);
   ```
3. You never check if `malloc()` returns `NULL`, that is bad practice.
4. [Do not cast the return value of malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495_)
5. Do not use `strlen()` as the condition of a loop unless the length of the string changes inside the loop, because `strlen()` computes the length of the string on each call, so you are making an O(n) algorithm O(n<sup>2</sup>).
6. The standard requires that `sizeof(char) == 1`, so it's just cluttering your code.

This is your own code fixed to address the issues mentioned above

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **
str_all_rotations(const char *const data)
 {
    int    index;
    char **all_rotations;
    char  *double_data;
    int    length;

    if (data == NULL)
        return NULL;
    length        = strlen(data);
    index         = 0;
    all_rotations = malloc(length * sizeof(*all_rotations));
    if (all_rotations == NULL)
        return NULL;
    double_data = malloc(2 * length + 1);
    if (double_data == NULL)
        goto cleanup;
    for (index = 0 ; index < length ; index++)
     {
        all_rotations[index] = malloc(1 + length);
        if (all_rotations[index] != NULL && index < 4)
            continue;
        goto cleanup;
     }
    memcpy(double_data, data, length);
    memcpy(double_data + length, data, length);

    double_data[2 * length] = '\0';
    for (index = 0 ; index < length ; index++)
     {
        memcpy(all_rotations[index], double_data + index, length);
        all_rotations[index][length] = '\0';
     }
    free(double_data);

    return all_rotations;

cleanup:
    while (index >= 0)
        free(all_rotations[index--]);
    free(all_rotations);
    free(double_data);

    return NULL;
 }

int
main(void)
 {
    char  *str  = "omgillsetyouonfire";
    char **asdf = str_all_rotations(str);

    if (asdf != NULL)
     {
        for (int i = 0 ; str[i] != '\0' ; i++)
         {
            printf("%s\n", asdf[i]);
            free(asdf[i]);
         }
        free(asdf);
     }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You made a mistake `char *double_data = malloc(2 * ( 1 + len));` should be `char *double_data = malloc(2 * len + 1 + );`

Comment: @EdHeal Oops I am allocating the `'\0'` twice!, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Your suggestions are great, thank You :)
Edit : I'm sorry for including strlen in loop condition and for not checking the return value of malloc, it's just a consequence of editing my original code to be less boilerplate for the actual question.

Comment: @NikolaNinkovic never edit the original code if it introduces this kind of things, because it might generate this kind of answer. And though it is good to minimize the sample code, remembert that it must reproduce the problematic behavior.